# Iterating through elements and adding index number

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why does this code add `class=hello5` to all the h2 elements upon being clicked? There are 4 h2 elements.

```
for (i=0; i < $('h2').length; i++) {
  $('#' + i).click(function(index) {
    $(this).addClass('hello' + i)
  })
};
```

I want it to add `class=hello0`, `class=hello1`, etc.

HTML:

```
<h2 id="0">0</h2>
<h2 id="1">1</h2>
<h2 id="2">2</h2>
<h2 id="3">3</h2>
```

Do I have to add another loop? I'm confused. Thanks.

Comment: element id do not start with numeric value.

Comment: @ravisoni: It can in HTML5.

Comment: @aaa Check the answer and working fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i` in your callback is the same `i` that you're incrementing. By the time those callback functions are triggered, `i`'s value will be `8`, so all of the callbacks will add the same class.

Avoid creating event handlers in loops in general. It's much easier to just select those elements at once and add a single event handler to all of them:

```
$('h2').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('hello' + this.id);
});
```

[Demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rw6WE/)

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is that you are expecting the paramater for handler as index but it is not, it is eventObject.

You better to use .each() function like this:

```
$("h2").each(function(index, item){
   $(item).click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       $(this).addClass("hello" + index);
   })
})
```

Comment: You could just do `$('h2').addClass(function(i) { return 'hello' + i; });`, but neither wouldn't trigger when the elements are clicked.

Comment: Thank you for remark. I missed that OP needs to add class by click. And I didn't know that I can use addClass that way.

Answer (score 0):

I edited your html snippet :

```
<h2 id="id0">0</h2>
<h2 id="id1">1</h2>
<h2 id="id2">2</h2>
<h2 id="id3">3</h2>
```

Try this code :

```
$('h2[id^="id"]').click(function(index){
    var idx = $(this).index();
    $(this).addClass('hello' + idx)
});
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/L7z3y/)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Jbh3q/203/

```
$("h2").each(function(index,element){
   $(element).addClass("hello" + index);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Because at the time click event is fire. Variable `i` is finish loop and it get the value 4. The   solution is use must get the index of `h2` element and assign to class. I have a little bit change :

```
$().ready(function () {
    for (i = 0; i < $('h2').length; i++) {
        $('#' + i).click(function (index) {
            $(this).addClass('hello' +$("h2").index( $(this)))
        })
    };
})
```

[Demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rw6WE/)